# error to configuring Drupal on docker desktop

Tags: docker, docker-compose, drupal

I need to install drupal via docker compose and mount directories on my local. I am using docker desktop on windows, docker compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
drupal-d:
image: drupal:latest
ports:
  - "8080:80"
depends_on:
  - db-d
volumes:
  - //c/Project/drupal/modules:/opt/drupal/web/modules
  - //c/Project/drupal/profiles:/opt/drupal/web/profiles
  - //c/Project/drupal/themes:/opt/drupal/web/themes
  - //c/Project/drupal/sites:/opt/drupal/web/sites
db-d:
image: mysql:latest
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxx
  MYSQL_DATABASE: xxx
  MYSQL_USER: xxx
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: xxx
volumes:
  - //c/Project/drupal/data:/var/lib/mysql
```

But after runnig docker compose, and start configuring Drupal, I got this error :

```
Writable (public download method)
The directory sites/default/files does not exist. An automated attempt to create this directory failed, possibly due to a permissions problem. To proceed with the installation, either create the directory and modify its permissions manually or ensure that the installer has the permissions to create it automatically. For more information, see INSTALL.txt or the online handbook.
```

The data has been mount on the link, But Drupal files are empty.